# Editing a pre-populated sqlite database core-data managed in IOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I want to add & delete new entries in my app. When I add or delete it should also do the same action to the sqlite database. But how?

The entity I want to manage is called "fugitive". Down below is my first view controller.m(which contains the tableview and the nsmutable array *items) code:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

iBountyHunterAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iBountyHunterAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Fugitive"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error;
}

self.items = mutableFetchResults;
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Even the slightest tip will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps you have the wrong approach here.
Without seeing much of your other code I can't say too much however the following is how CoreData should work:

You update any changes to CoreData FIRST, and then CoreData will notify the delegate/observer that the data is to be reloaded, and that is where you update your objects cache and notify the table view to update.

Therefore do not update the data array yourself, you merely cache it from CoreData.

Comment: Would you mind if I gave you a link with the project to help me out a bit? Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's probably unnecessary, why don't you reference Apple's great locations example from the Xcode library, it's very simple.